# Graph in blender a function of two variables,

Tags: modeling, mesh, mathematics

I would like to know if there is any way to be able to graph in blender a function of two variables, for example Sin (x y2) for the domain of x from -3 to 3, the domain of y from -2 to 2, to get something like the following image:

[image]

Clear this without axes, nor box,to later add some material and other things. I searched on YouTube for something similar but without success

I hope someone can help me

Comment: [How can I generate an object from a mathematical function?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63697/2217) may also be of help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an addon shipped by default with Blender called *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* capable of doing this. It is disabled by default and can be activated from the *User Preferences* dialog.

Start by opening *File > User Preferences > Addons* then search for `Extra` and activate the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* addon.

Then in the *3D View* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add > Mesh > Math Function > Z Math Function* or *XYZ Math Function* depending on what you want.

Introduce the function equation in the corresponding fields and adjust precision as necessary.

See [related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/how-can-i-create-a-3d-curve-saddle-shape/73752#73752) for more details.

[image: Z Function]