# Creating mesh on a surface with two variables

Tags: mesh, add-on, mathematics

I have an equation like this:  $\cos(z)+\sin(x)+\sin(y)=1$ and I want to do something like:

[Graph in blender a function of two variables,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/graph-in-blender-a-function-of-two-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I followed the proposed method in the same post. It was great and worked fine for many cases.

1) I cannot use `arccosine(1-sin(x)-sin(y))`. `arccos` and `acos` don't work either. 
What is the solution? 
Thanks in advance for your comments.

2) is there any possible way to determine a range for $z$ as well?

Comment: Not sure but according to this thread you may try `cos**(-1)` for inverse funtion of `cos`

Comment: Googling a bit finally turned up a free online plotter that can do implicit surfaces, and your equation gave me this: http://i.imgur.com/poiqcRq.png. Is that what you're expecting? You can find the plotter at http://matkcy.github.io/surface.html.

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thanks. That is exactly what I want. Actually, this is another equation I like to have! How can I add more vertices (say se=pecifically N points) on the surface and save them in a .txt file?

Comment: Is there any way to also calculate the normal vector to this surface at each of these points on the surface and save them in a separate file?

Answer (score 1):

The Python function *'acos'* has a parameter's domain between -1 and 1. If the parameter is out of this, you get a 'domain error'.

So for instance, you can set the following formula:

```
acos( (1-sin(x)-sin(y)) % (1 if (1-sin(x)-sin(y)) >0 else -1 ) )
```

or more simple (using *'fmod'* which is C style modulo as Python's native modulo sign rely on the divisor sign)

```
acos( fmod( (1-sin(x)-sin(y)), 1 ) )
```

which is limiting the parameter's values.

Or alternatively to have a linear transition, limiting the parameter value like this:

```
acos( ((1-sin(x)-sin(y)) + 1) / 4 )
```

The result is the following:

[image]

or:

[image]

For your information, the math functions available in the addon:

```
safe_list = ['math', 'acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'atan2', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh',
    'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'hypot',
    'ldexp', 'log', 'log10', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians',
    'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh']
```

And these links to stack overflow:

- [About acos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637400/why-do-i-get-valueerror-math-domain-error).
- [About modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/negative-numbers-modulo-in-python).

Comment: Thanks lemon for your reply. I understand the domain for acos, but I do not understand why It does not work. Can you please check this link. http://matkcy.github.io/surface.html sent by brasshat. Please read my last two comments above. This is what I want. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: @Mohsen The sine function produces a value from -1 to 1 inclusive, and since x and y are independent of each other, `sin(x)+sin(y)` has a range of -2 to 2 inclusive. The problem occurs when this gets negative, `1-sin(x)-sin(y)` will then be greater than 1, which is an invalid value for acos. `1-sin(x)-sin(y)` is the same as `1-(sin(x)+sin(y))` and subtracting a negative value is equivalent to adding its absolute value.

Comment: @Duane, thanks. Got it. The arccosine domain is [0, pi]. So, it cannot be negative while 1-sin(x)-sin(y) can be negative sometimes. So, any idea for how can I make such a graph? http://matkcy.github.io/surface.html

Comment: @Mohsen You got the idea right, but the numbers wrong. The domain of arccos is [-1, 1] and 1-sin(x)-sin(y) has values in the range [-1, 3]. As for a solution, I have none, but I did post a workaround as an answer to [creating mesh on an isosurface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79576/creating-mesh-on-an-isosurface/79943#79943), and there's also an [answer by Mutant Bob](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79576/creating-mesh-on-an-isosurface/79737#79737) to that question, suggesting [the marching cubes algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes).