# How to create a path (curve) from an equation?

Tags: bezier-curves

So what I want to do is draw an orbit of a planet (say, Mercury) with a proper shape and orientation. Then I want to make a sphere with a texture of Mercury and make it move along the orbit (with the orbit itself being drawn too).

I've found one way or drawing the orbit through XYZ Function Surface (Add Mesh: Extra Objects add-on, if I'm not mistaken) - then I just set the equations for X, Y and Z and get the properly oriented ellipse. This works fine, but Blender doesn't consider it as an object, I think. Nor it allows me to link any object to that curve. Nor would the orbit itself be rendered in that case (I think it's considered as an "empty" in Blender terms - I'm completely new to the program, so might be wrong).

So the question is: can I do all that at all? Maybe working through Python console to draw a curve is the way out? I have no experience with Python either, so any hints on where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not convert the resulting "ellispe" mesh into a Bezier curve afterwards? Should easily give you access to all you need. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/graph-in-blender-a-function-of-two-variables/

Comment: it's 3 A.M, and its the only link i found... [Blender Tutorial: Math Marvels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdoFjxu605c)