# How can I correct more faces at the same time?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am making this stylized "illusionist pendant", that basically has two halves, that turn forming a heart and open (sorry for the poor explanation). I already have the heart modeled but if I try to rotate half of it the silhouettes don't match up. So how could I fix that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have fixed them now, but please next time use the "add image" tool that is provided by the question editor, as it formats images perfectly...

Comment: Might find [this link useful](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/how-can-i-generate-an-object-from-a-mathematical-function)