# Drawing mathematical functions using Blender

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to draw 
Scherk's Minimal Surfaces (which is  e^z*cosy=cosx) using Blender?
Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph in blender a function of two variables,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74410/graph-in-blender-a-function-of-two-variables)

Comment: An answer that might help with this class of equations is https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/how-can-i-generate-an-object-from-a-mathematical-function

Answer (score 1):

1.Add
2.Math Function
The functions on left side are fully customizable.
Hope this will work, try!

[image]