# How to make a spiral torus?

Tags: modeling, scripting, geometry

How to make a spiral torus as shown below?

I do know how to make various spirals in Blender, but this one escapes me and makes my head spin (forgive the pun). I believe it consists of several torus spirals put together and just spins around Z axis, creating an optical illusion. I tried twisting a torus spiral in Blender but it looks different. Perhaps this can only be made by script. It's a good puzzle.

[image]

Comment: Goes the other way to the slinky like torus spiral.  Theoretically these two answers [loxodrome on sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42159/15543) and [heart mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63706/15543) can be combined. To create a loxodrome on a torus.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a new word "loxodrome" :)