# How to slim down a cuboid?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I would like to slim a cuboid with the base of the heart. I want to slim it down only in relation to the X and Y axes by exactly 0.4 mm. I would like the edges of the new and old hearts to be 0.4mm apart.

The scaling operation does not do what I would like. Gaps of various widths are created. I wish the gaps were 0.4mm wide everywhere.

I attached a picture from another program because it was easier for me to show my problem. The picture shows what I don't want to get.

Does anyone have an idea how to efficiently modify an object the way I would like?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/how-can-i-generate-an-object-from-a-mathematical-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the heart shaped base, then make sure to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to apply scale and rotation. Then select the surface and inset  <kbd>I</kbd>. You can type in the exact distance in the pop up on the lower left of the screen.

If you want to copy it to create a second object, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>,  <kbd>P</kbd>, then *Selected*.

You can extrude that face to make a smaller heart.

Comment: Wow it works! Exactly as I needed. Thank you so much, you are wonderful. I already thought that this could not be done.